# Django - Erro ao salvar no Banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, python, django, formulário, sqlite3

Os dados não estão sendo salvos no Banco de Dados e o Django não esta gerando Erro,
porem quando crio um objeto de `Livro` e tento salvar pelo shell ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tentei procurar soluções mas sem sucesso! Estou usando o sqlite3! Django 1.6.2 e python 2.7! O projeto [esta disponível no github](https://github.com/Sniickers/Two).

Models.py:

```
class Biblioteca(models.Model):

    endereco = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    telefone = models.IntegerField(max_length = 11)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome

class Livro(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    publicacao = models.IntegerField()
    autor = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    editora = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    sinopse = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    biblioteca = models.ForeignKey(Biblioteca)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.titulo, self.autor)
```

Forms.py:

```
class FormLivro(forms.Form):

    codigo = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    publicacao = forms.IntegerField()
    autor = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    editora = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    genero = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    sinopse = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    titulo = forms.CharField(max_length=150)

def save(self):

    codigo = self.cleaned_data.get('codigo')# Acessando os Fields
    publicacao = self.cleaned_data.get('publicacao')         
    autor = self.cleaned_data.get('autor')
    editora = self.cleaned_data.get('editora')
    genero = self.cleaned_data.get('genero')
    sinopse = self.cleaned_data.get('sinopse')
    titulo = self.cleaned_data.get('titulo')

    novo_livro = Livro(
        codigo = codigo,
        publicacao = publicacao,
        autor = autor,
        editora = editora,
        genero = genero,
        sinopse = sinopse,
        titulo = titulo
    )
    novo_livro.save()
    return novo_livro 

def clean_codigo(self):
    codigo = self.cleaned_data.get('codigo')
    if Livro.object.filter(email = email):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Codigo já cadastrado!')
    return codigo
```

Views.py:

```
def cadLivro(request):

    livros = Livro.objects.all() # Lista de livros
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormLivro(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # Processando o Formulario
            novo_livro = form.save()
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nCadLivro'))
    else:
        form = FormLivro()

    return render(request, 'cadastro_livro.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código no Github está diferente do código da pergunta. No modelo `Livro`, o campo `codigo` está como `IntegerField` em vez de `CharField`. Por essa razão, ocorre o erro mencionado ao se tentar salvar o `Livro` pelo shell. Mas usando um valor numérico nesse campo, ele salva normalmente (seja usando um inteiro, ou uma string representando um inteiro na base 10).

Tentei testar também pelo view, mas ele nem compila, então sugiro resolver esse (e outros) problema caso precise de ajuda nisso também. E lembre-se sempre de verificar se o banco está coerente com os modelos - pois se você modifica algum campo no modelo, rodar `syncdb` de novo não vai fazer nada, é preciso destruir sua tabela e criá-la de novo (por exemplo usando `reset`; **cuidado:** isso apaga todos os dados da tabela). Em breve, o Django dará suporte a migração de esquema, mas no momento isso não é feito nativamente (só por bibliotecas externas, como o South).

P.S. Seu método `__unicode__` não funciona, pois ele retorna uma tupla em vez de uma string. Sugiro alterá-lo para (por exemplo):

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode((self.titulo, self.autor))
```

Comment: Realizei as correções e atualizei no GitHub, agora esta retornando: IntegrityError at /cadLivro/ library_livro.biblioteca_id may not be NULL

Obs: Já tenho uma tabela Biblioteca criada no Banco de Dados

Comment: @Snickers Quanto a isso, o problema é que quando você cria um novo `Livro` no `forms.py` você não atribui a referência para uma `Biblioteca`, ou um ID de uma biblioteca (afinal, um `Livro` pertence a uma `Biblioteca`). Se quiser que possa existir livros sem biblioteca, coloque a chave estrangeira como *nullable* (`biblioteca = models.ForeignKey(Biblioteca, null=True, blank=True, default=None)`). Senão, inclua uma opção no seu formulário pro usuário escolher uma biblioteca. P.S. Só avisando, seu `views.py` diz que está em `utf-8` no cabeçalho, mas na realidade está em `Windows-1252` / `Cp1252`.

Comment: Entendi, quanto ao relacionamento Biblioteca -> Livro. Eu realmente fiquei na duvida na hora de criar os models pois posso dizer que um Livro pertence a uma Biblioteca (OneToOne), mas tbm posso dizer também que uma Biblioteca possui vários Livros (ManyToOne / ForeingKey)

Comment: "one to one" significaria que a biblioteca só tem um único livro... :P Creio que - dependendo da aplicação - possa ser "many to one" (o livro é uma coisa física, que só pode pertencer a uma única biblioteca) ou "many to many" (o livro X possui N cópias, cada uma numa biblioteca diferente - talvez mais de um na mesma). A forma como você implementou está correta pro "many to one", só resta decidir se existem livros "independentes" (i.e. que não estão em nenhuma biblioteca) ou não.